# Checking the desired checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of Subjects , which are used to populate 
a group of checkboxes. And I have a list of SubjectIds,
where, the values of the Subjects match with a Subject Id , then
the checkbox will be checked.

For this The html code is:

```
<div ng-repeat="subj in Subjects">
    <div ng-repeat="sub in SubjectIds">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="subjectModel[subj.SubjectId]" ng-checked="subj.SubjectId==sub"/>{{subj.SubjectName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This code checks the desired checkboxes, but the checkboxes are repeated by the number of the items in SubjectIds.

Comment: you don't need the second `ng-repeat`, it's not your typical for loop. You can pull out the id with `SubjectIds[$index]`

Comment: use some intermediate function which queries `SubjectIds` and simply decide weather it's checked or not `or` merge two array and make it one & use ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="subj in Subjects">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="subjectModel[subj.SubjectId]" ng-checked="SubjectIds.indexOf(subj.SubjectId) != -1"/>{{subj.SubjectName}}

</div>
```

Comment: This does not work, suppose if the SubjectIds are 101,102,103,104,105, then all the checkboxes are checked properly, but if SubjectIds are 101,102,104 , then only 101 and 102 are checked.

Comment: Can you write a function which map $index to proper ID? length of Subjects and SubjectIds are equal, but order of them is not equal??

Comment: use this instead of last one `ng-checked="SubjectIds.indexOf(subj.SubjectId) != -1"` @Hoster

Answer (score 0):

You need a logic that checks if the index is in the given array. I suggest you use `.indexOf()` method for arrays. Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Subjects = [
  {"SubjectId":1,"SubjectName":"Name1"},
  {"SubjectId":12,"SubjectName":"Name12"},
  {"SubjectId":101,"SubjectName":"Name101"},
  ];

  $scope.SubjectIds = [1, 101];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="subj in Subjects">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="subjectModel[subj.SubjectId]" 
      ng-checked="SubjectIds.indexOf(subj.SubjectId)!=-1"/> 
        {{subj.SubjectName}}
  </div>
</div>
```